# Is this an equivalence relation on $A$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let $S$ be a non-empty set, $A$ be the set of all functions from $S$ to $S$, and $B$ be the set of all bijective functions from $S$ to $S$. Define the following relation on $A$:

$$f \sim g \quad :\iff\quad \exists h \in B :\quad f\circ h = g.$$

Is this an equivalence relation on $A$?

Comment: can you define equivalence relation ? that may help you or at least show the misunderstanding of what it is.

Comment: Find out whether it is symmetric, reflexive and transitive.

Comment: **Hint:** since $h\in B$, the set of bijective functions from $S$ to $S$, that implies that $h^{-1}$ is also an element of $B$.  Also worth mentioning is that the composition of bijective functions is again bijective and that the identity function is bijective.

Comment: @rldias I don't even know where to begin. I tried proving if it's reflexive but I think that for f~f $\implies$ fh = f and h has to equal 1 which in not bijective. I'm pretty sure that I'm wrong but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: It would be instructive, though perhaps tedious, to work out the entire relation for $S = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ for $n=1,2,3,4$ if you can. It is good to convince yourself something, empirically if possible, is true before proving it.

Comment: @PratyushChopra what do you mean by "$h$ has to equal $1$ which in not bijective"? I think you are confused with the notation $fh$. This is not a multiplication, it's *composition of functions*.

Comment: @Krish what I meant was that h(x) = 1 is not a bijective function because it is not one to one. But is it true?

Answer (score 1):

#### Reflexivity

Does $f \sim f$ ?  Let $\mathbf 1$ be the identity function.  Obviously it is bijective, hence $\mathbf 1 \in B$.  Therefore $f = f \circ \mathbf 1$.

#### Symmetry

If $f \sim g$, does $g \sim f$ ?  To prove it, remember that if $h : S \to S$ is a bijective function, it defines an inverse function $h^{-1} : S \to S$ such that $h \circ h^{-1} = \mathbf 1$.

#### Transitivity

If $f \sim g$ and $g \sim e$, does $f \sim e$ ? To prove it, remember that if $h$ and $k$ are two bijective functions, so is $h \circ k$.

Comment: wait.. where did the k come from??

Comment: My bad, I used the symbol $h$ to mean two very different things : once as a function in the relation, once as the bijection to check the relation.  I'm fixing that.